# Fastest Way to Shingle from Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shingles

I need the *fastest possible* way to shingle strings from a data frame and then create a master list.

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d=['Hello', 'Helloworld']
f=pd.DataFrame({'strings':d})
f
    strings
0   Hello
1   Helloworld
```

I'd like to generate a list shingled strings (of length 3) like this:
(All possible 3-letter combinations are included.)

```
[['Hel', 'ell', 'llo'],['Hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'low', 'owo', 'wor', 'orl', 'rld']]
```

... and a master list of all unique values like this:

```
['wor', 'Hel', 'ell', 'owo', 'llo', 'rld', 'orl', 'low']
```

I can do it as follows, but I suspect there is a much faster way:

```
#Shingle into strings of exactly 3
def shingle(word):
    r = [word[i:i + 3] for i in range(len(word) - 3 + 1)]
    return [''.join(t) for t in r]
#Shingle (i.e. "hello" -> "hel","ell",'llo')
r=[shingle(w) for w in f['strings']]
#Get all elements into one list:
import itertools
colsunq=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(r))
#Remove duplicates:
colsunq=list(set(colsunq))
colsunq

['wor', 'Hel', 'ell', 'owo', 'llo', 'rld', 'orl', 'low']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 4 years late, but here's an answer. I don't think that it's possible to determine the "fastest" way since that's heavily dependent on hardware and algorithms. (It might fall under something similar to [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).)

But, I needed to shingle over 11 million files. I put each of the words in a numpy array and ran the following code.

```py
shingles = set()

for i in range(words.shape[0] - w + 1):
    a = words[i:i + w]
    shingles.add(tuple(a))
```

This code processed 27.2 billion words in about 6 hours.

Answer (score 2):

This works if you want to shingle a series of words:

```
def shingles(word, n = 3):
    return [word[i:i + n] for i in range(len(word) - n + 1)]

df['shingles'] = df2.to_shingle_col.map(shingles)
```

So, if you have something like

[123,456,789,123,456] you'll get

[[123,456,789],[456,789,123],[789,123,456]]